# List index out of range error caused by empty cells when using CSV reader in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, csvreader

I'm trying to figure out how to deal with empty cells when iterating through a CSV file. I am currently receiving an IndexError whenever I run the loop. This is because the rows are not empty, just some of the cells in the columns that I am iterating through.

I am using a standard for loop for the iteration. Is there a way that I can skip the empty cells when running the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to handle the exception with a `try` and `except` block.

```py
try:
    print('This is your code')
except IndexError:
    print('This is where you handle the error if it occurs')
```

If it is appropriate to ignore the exception, you may use the `pass` keyword. This is a null statement and is used to maintain proper syntax.

Here is some [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) regarding exceptions management in Python.

Comment: I think this is close. I'm getting an error with this too. I think the problem is I now have empty values from the empty cells. Is there a way to skip the empty cells instead of bypassing the exception?